# Overriding a CSS rule for p tag fails

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here is the markup that I have

```
<div class="sign-in ">
<form> 
<fieldset>
<p class="note">
Note
</p>
</div>
```

The CSS rule that one of my stylesheet has is this :

```
.sign-in p{
margin: 5px 80px;
}
```

I need this style rule to be overwritten for p tags that have a note class along with that.

SO I apply this style rule

```
.sign-in .note p{
margin:0px;
}.
```

However, the original style rule still sustains itself instead of being overridden by the new style rule that I have applied.

Here is this in js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fNepf/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you close your form and fieldset tags correctly as well: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/sbG6g/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector should be:

```
.sign-in p.note {
   margin:0px;
}
```

You were selecting all `<p>`'s which are descendants of the class `.note`.

[**jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fNepf/1/)

Comment: got it, what if this p tag had two classes instead of one

Comment: You could do `p.note.test` if you have two classes on the `<p>`

Comment: @Adrift You're too fast :P

Comment: OP: You don't have to modify anything if this element has 25 classes and you're only interested by the `.note` class. Though if you only want to select paragraphs having both note and test classes, then yes `p.test.note` is what you're searching for. Note: you don't need to add `p` the element to your selector if there are no other elements that could have this class inside `.sign-in`. A class selector is more specific than an element selector so it overrides p in all cases

Comment: @FelipeAls I already knew all that, was just playing it safe :)

Comment: My bad, forgot to start my comment by "OP: "

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong,

use:

```
.sign-in .note{
    margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector should instead be:

```
.sign-in p.note {
margin: 0px;
}
```

As the selector you posted is looking for a `<p>` that is a descendant of an element with class `.note` instead of a `<p>` element *with* the class `.note`

http://jsfiddle.net/fNepf/2/

If you have two classes on the `<p>` you could use `.sign-in p.note.test {}`:

http://jsfiddle.net/fNepf/3/